# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60), found shape=(None, 59)

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I am getting an error using the following R code. The dataset is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+news+popularity. I am trying to build a dense neural network in order to solve a regression problem. I am attempting to predict the value of the variable "shares" using all the other variables"

Thank you in advance

```
#Loading libraries 

library(keras)
library(mlbench)
library(ggplot2)
library(neuralnet)
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

#Loading the dataset 

df <- read.csv("/Users/prathamdave/Desktop/OnlineNewsPopularity.csv")

#Inspecting the dataset 

str(df)
glimpse(df)

#Preliminary data cleaning

data <- df[2:61]
str(df)
data %<>% mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric)

#Preparing data

#Matrix
data <- as.matrix(data)
dimnames(data) <- NULL

#Partition 
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(0.7,.03))
training <- data[ind==1, 1:59]
test <- data[ind==2, 1:59]
trainingtarget <- data[ind==1, 60]
testtarget <- data[ind==2, 60]

#Normalizing data
m <- colMeans(training)
s <- apply(training, 2, sd)
training <- scale(training, center = m, scale = s)
test <- scale(test, center = m, scale = s)

#Creating the model specification
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 41, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(60)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

#Compile
model %>% compile(loss = 'mse',
                  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                  metrics = 'mae')

#Fit Model
mymodel <- model %>%
  fit(
    training,
    trainingtarget,
    epochs = 180,
    batch_size = 32,
    validation_split = 0.2
  )
```

output

```
Epoch 1/180
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: in user code:
<... omitted ...>te/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/prathamdave/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/Users/prathamdave/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/Users/prathamdave/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 60), found shape=(None, 59)

See `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your data has 59 features and 1 target. So you need to have an `input_shape` of 59 instead of 60. You can use the following reproducible code:

```
#Loading libraries 

library(keras)
library(mlbench)
library(ggplot2)
library(neuralnet)
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

#Loading the dataset 

df <- read.csv("OnlineNewsPopularity/OnlineNewsPopularity.csv")

#Inspecting the dataset 

str(df)
glimpse(df)

#Preliminary data cleaning

data <- df[2:61]
str(df)
data %<>% mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric)

#Preparing data

#Matrix
data <- as.matrix(data)
dimnames(data) <- NULL

#Partition 
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = T, prob = c(0.7,.03))
training <- data[ind==1, 1:59]
test <- data[ind==2, 1:59]
trainingtarget <- data[ind==1, 60]
testtarget <- data[ind==2, 60]

#Normalizing data
m <- colMeans(training)
s <- apply(training, 2, sd)
training <- scale(training, center = m, scale = s)
test <- scale(test, center = m, scale = s)

#Creating the model specification
model <- keras_model_sequential() 
model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 41, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(59)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

#Compile
model %>% compile(loss = 'mse',
                  optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                  metrics = 'mae')

#Fit Model
mymodel <- model %>%
  fit(
    training,
    trainingtarget,
    epochs = 180,
    batch_size = 32,
    validation_split = 0.2
  )
```

Output:

[image]